# List comprehension with zipped iterators and conditionals

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have been trying to populate a list such that if another list containing a boolean at index j is True, I perform an operation(simple regex) on another list else choose to pass(implicitly).

```
import re
maskNan = [True, True, False, True, False]
stringList = ['foo.abc','foo.def','foo.ghi','foo.jkl']
filteredNames = [re.findall(r'foo.(\w+)', i)[0] if j for i,j in zip(columnHeaders,maskNaN)]
```

This gives me `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` at end of for

while this works fine

```
justNames = [re.findall(r'foo.(\w+)', i)[0] for i in columnHeaders]
```

giving

```
['abc','def','ghi','jkl']
```

Comment: If should be last in list comprehension

Comment: The problem is resolved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on @SimonF's comment, correct expression should be

```
filteredNames = [re.findall(r'foo.(\w+)', i)[0] for i,j in zip(columnHeaders,maskNaN) if j ]
```